# MySQL - Discard record if not unique with condition

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to built this query, I think is a little bit complex to optimize it without using subqueries.

```
| baggage_id | checkpoint | status |
|------------|------------|--------|
| 1          | 3          | 1      |
| 2          | 3          | 1      |
| 2          | 5          | 1      |
| 3          | 3          | 0      |
| 4          | 3          | 1      |
| 5          | 3          | 1      |
| 6          | 3          | 0      |
```

This should be returning

```
| baggage_id | checkpoint | status |
|------------|------------|--------|
| 1          | 3          | 1      |
| 4          | 3          | 1      |
| 5          | 3          | 1      |
```

I only requires the bagagges_id where:

- checkpoint = 3
- status = 1
- There is not baggage_id with checkpoint = 5 AND status = 1

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is a LEFT JOIN with a collapse on the set to exclude.

```
SELECT *
FROM bags b
LEFT JOIN (
   -- Find set of baggage_id's to exclude
   -- The group-by is to collapse the set to distinct baggage ID's
   -- to avoid increasing multiplicity.
   SELECT baggage_id, 1 as hasCheckpoint5AndStatus1
   FROM bags
   WHERE checkpoint = 5 AND status = 1
   GROUP BY baggage_id
) b2
ON b.baggage_id = b2.baggage_id
WHERE b.checkpoint = 3 AND b.status = 1
-- If NULL, then baggage_id is NOT excluded
AND b2.hasCheckpoint5AndStatus1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to skip the subquery. My current query is pretty similar

`SELECT cp1.*, cp2.* FROM checkpoints AS cp1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM checkpoints WHERE checkpoint = 5 AND status = 1) AS cp2 ON cp1.baggage_id = cp2.baggage_id WHERE cp1.checkpoint = 3 AND cp1.status = 1 AND cp2.baggage_id IS NULL;
`

Comment: @noisedan It should be considered a [derived table query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and not a "subquery", as "subquery" often has negative connotations due to [ab]use inside select output clauses.

Comment: Thanks, I will use your query then :)